# Nexus on an internet server?

Tags: maven, nexus

I am reading [Repository Management with Nexus](http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/index.html) and the focus of it seems to act as a local proxy. Instead I would like to use it to distribute custom artifacts (very few of them, like less than 10). Some of them might be open source and some private to a company or another company (I'm a consultant).

Before I read the whole book and find out that Nexus is not for me, do you think this is a reasonable use case? I'm only at chapter 2, so I don't know what kind of authorization can Nexus provide for a single artifact. One option would be to install multiple copies of Nexus in different path, with http password I guess, albeit probably not the smartest.

The purpose of this question is to know if Nexus is suitable to distribute private artifacts to different companies with different privileges and to work on the internet, not in a intranet, or I should look for other options. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nexus allows you to have both hosted and proxy repositories. Apart from this it allows you to have virtual repositories and groups. Groups can be used for grouping your repositories under one name. So... you can set up a repository containing some artifacts that should be visible only to your clients, another one for your OSS artifacts and then group them for some client.

You can also use the Pro version, which is paid, and, as far as I recall had this sort of feature.

Comment: Even the OSS version of Nexus has this core capability to define repository targets and then assign permissions. You can do exactly what is asked.

Answer (score 5):

I think this is a very reasonable thing to ask of a Nexus installation. I've used both Artifactory and Nexus (2 of the most popular Maven repos), and found Nexus to be much more flexible and full-featured. Sonatype has a similar setup to what you are asking about for their open source artifact hosting. In that case, I believe the security only restricts uploads, not downloads, but I'm 99% certain that downloads can also be secured. JBoss also has a large public Nexus installation.

Do keep in mind, though, that Sonatype has both an OSS edition and a commercial edition of Nexus. The segregation you're looking for may be a commercial feature only. But I would still recommend Nexus for the purpose you described, as long as the cost isn't prohibitive. *Hint:* I think you'll start to really find what you're looking for when you get to chapter 6.